# Getting a concatenated string date from html to php via form

Tags: php, html, forms, date

The following code gets the date in the form 6/4/2016

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var currentDate = (month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
document.write(currentDate)
</script>
```

I've tried several different ways to submit the date as a hidden field in a form to use as the primary key in a SQL database.

```
<input type="hidden" name="DateSubmitted" value=($month + "/" + $day + "/" + $year)>
```

^ shows  $month  as what was submitted in the array

```
<?php $currentDate = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="mDateJoined" value="<?php echo $currentDate; ?>">
```

^is blank in the array

```
<input type="hidden" name="DateJoined" value=currentDate>
```

^displays currentdate as the text submitted.

Comment: Your second option should work fine. Have you examined the page's source to ensure the date is getting into the hidden field? If so then make sure you're calling it correctly when you add it to your database. Although wouldn't it be easier just to use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value in MySQL?

Comment: I was trying to use just the date as a primary key for a register closing form. I don't need the time. I'd like to be able to search it by date. I'm fairly new to SQL.    I actually got it using $currentDate = date('Y-m-d'); on the php page that the form data is submitted to. I'll just use that for the sql insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than submit the date from the form to the php page, I just included

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
```

on the php page for sql insertion.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume you want to read the clock of the client computer, which might be wrong, not just have the date and time the form was submitted? If the latter is the case use the suggestion of assemblyhelpneededplease, it is more reliable.

The mistake you seem to make is to mix HTML, Javascript, and PHP. These three are quite different beasts. You should have a clear idea about what is which. This PHP script will get the date from the computer of your visitor:

```
<?php

echo '<script>
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth()+1;
var day   = currentTime.getDate();
var year  = currentTime.getFullYear();
var currentDate = month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
document.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mDateJoined\" value=\""+currentDate+"\">");
</script>';
```

So this is a PHP script outputting Javascript which generates HTML. Complicated. Better follow the suggestion of assemblyhelpneededplease!